# xslt produces a result that does not end with a carriage return (newline)

Tags: linux, xslt, newline

I have an xslt script that transforms an xml file to another xml file.
The problem I'm having is that the resulting xml file does not end with a newline like a well behaved linux file.

I'm using `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>` for the code to be nicely idented.

Is there a way to tell xslt that this is Linux mode, and it should add a newline at the end of the output?

Thanks,
Anna

Comment: Can you explain what problems you get when the final newline is missing?

Comment: I think this is not XSLT problem but next-step-in-pipeline problem, wich it looks like it can't handle XML documents...

Comment: Yes, indeed its a next-step-in-pipeline problem. I just fixed the next step, and let it be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not an XML file ends in a newline *should* be irrelevant.

However, you can try to add a newline manually, with the equivalent of this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="other/processing" />
  </root>
  <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" />
</xsl:template>
```

If this does not work for your XSL processor (i.e. the newline gets trimmed), you should consider changing your successive processing chain to ignore the "missing" newline.

Comment: I fixed the next-step-in-pipeline. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try method="text" and use the newline code(`&#10;`) where you need it

Comment: This did not work for me.
If I use method="text", then all of the xml I'm producing disappears.
If I add only the newline code, then it is being ignored.